# NSBasic/Palm 4.4 Tutorial

Tags: palm-os, garnet-os

Can someone please recommend me a very good tutorial for NSBasic 4.4 (please post a link).
I've came from the Handheld Basic background, then I recently used another IDE from a friend which has a version of NSBasic, but my friend develops in Handheld Basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NSBasic don't have much things check for [technotes](http://www.nsbasic.com/desktop/info/technotes/) if help. Or this [website](http://tutomania.com.br/livro/apostila-de-ns-basic--palm) in brazilian

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good book about NSBasic/Palm titled [NS Basic Programming for Palm OS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0969584466).  That's probably the best tutorial about the core language and UI designer.  It didn't have a very large print run, so used copies are still going in the $25-30 range on Amazon and half.com.

Answer (score 1):

NS Basic/Palm 7 is the current version. It comes with a whole menu of tutorials. Also, check out the TechNotes.

If you download the demo, you will see the tutorials under the Help menu.

NS Basic/Palm 4.4 is several years old.